# locus of midpoints of trajectories in a pool table

Tags: geometry

There are a square pool table and two points, $P$ and $Q$, inside it. There are of course infinite different ways to let a ball go from $P$ to $Q$ (hitting it just once). The question is: **if we consider all these trajectories and take the midpoint for each one of them, how many points do we have?**

Comment: How would you like to define the mid point when the ball bounces off the boundary multiple times?

Comment: You might find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800897/finding-beam-paths-using-reflection/2800951#2800951) helpful.